# Z-index button not clickable

Tags: html, css

I'm getting annoyed with a little problem. When I modify the z-index css attribute of my buttons (beacuse on scroll they overlaps on my top navbar and footer) they are not clickable yes, like there is something onto the button. How can I solve this problem?

This is my button:

```
<button class="btn waves-effect waves-light"><i class="small material-icons">add</i></button>
```

This is the CSS:

```
.waves-effect {
position: relative;
cursor: pointer;
display: inline-block;
overflow: hidden;
-webkit-user-select: none;
-moz-user-select: none;
-ms-user-select: none;
user-select: none;
-webkit-tap-highlight-color: transparent;
vertical-align: middle;
z-index: 0;
transition: .3s ease-out;
}
materialize3.css:5259
.btn, .btn-large {
text-decoration: none;
color: #fff;
background-color: #0091ea;
text-align: center;
letter-spacing: .5px;
transition: .2s ease-out;
cursor: pointer;
margin-left: 5px;
}
materialize3.css:5241
.btn, .btn-large, .btn-floating, .btn-large, .btn-flat {
font-size: 1rem;
outline: 0;
}
materialize3.css:5187
.btn, .btn-large, .btn-flat {
border: none;
border-radius: 2px;
display: inline-block;
height: 36px;
line-height: 36px;
padding: 0 2rem;
text-transform: uppercase;
vertical-align: middle;
-webkit-tap-highlight-color: transparent;
```

Comment: post your code. see how to create a [mcve]

Comment: I posted it now

Comment: If I change the z-index to '-1', the button doesn't work anymore @j08691

Comment: What do you expect a negative z-index to do?

Comment: @AlessioCorvaglia set others to 999 instead of setting the btn to -1

Comment: Using `z-index: -1;` places the button under the body. Use a positive z-index.

Answer (score 1):

You might be trying to give a negative value to the z-index, causing other divs to overlap the button and make it unclickable. Instead, try giving a positive value (greater than the z-index value of the button) to the navbar and footer.

Not sufficient code to debug. Describe your problem with a working model and you might get your issue resolved.

Comment: Thank you so much! I solved by giving 999 to the navbar and 1 to the buttons!