# CSS: z-index on image makes buttons not clickable

Tags: html, css

I've 2 buttons in my home banner. Because of stetics, I need to send image of banner to the most back, only in front of banner's background-color.

However, making this make unclickable my buttons. I've tried to with a positive index to these buttons but wthout results.

**CodePen**:

https://codepen.io/ogonzales/pen/YdvNqy

HTML:

```
{% load staticfiles %}

<div class="container-fluid my_home_banner my_header_bg_color">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-7">
            <br>
            <br>
            <div class="my_home_banner_left">
                <p class="my_home_banner_title">Stickers Personalizados</p>
                <p class="my_home_banner_subtitle">Easy online ordering, 4 day turnaround and free online proofs. Free
                    shipping.</p>
                <div class="row ">
                    <div class="col-md-6">
                        <a href="stickers" class="my_home_buttons btn btn-azul text-white btn-block">Comprar</a>
                    </div>
                    <br>
                    <div class="col-md-6">
                        <a href="{% url 'shop:SamplePackPage' %}"
                           class="my_home_buttons btn btn-naranja text-white btn-block">Muestras</a>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
            <br>
            <br>
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-5">
            <img class="my_home_banner_image" src="{% static 'img/banner-home.png' %}"
                 width="380px" height="240px">
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

**CSS:**

```
.my_header_bg_color {
    /*background-color: #FF6138;*/
    background-color: #00A388;
    z-index: -9000;
}

.my_home_buttons {

    z-index: 99999999;
}
```

Here is a similar question, but the solution don't apply here.

[Z-index 'breaks' slideshow click buttons](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51061624/z-index-breaks-slideshow-click-buttons)

Comment: `.my_header_bg_color ` remove that ridiculous `z-index: -9000`

Comment: I added position relative to your buttons and z-index:1 to your my home banner and your pen worked on my iPhone; couldn’t copy and paste the css mobile but try my suggestion

Answer (score 1):

Taken from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44249790/z-index-button-not-clickable):


*You might be trying to give a negative value to the z-index, causing other divs to overlap the button and make it unclickable. Instead, try giving a positive value (greater than the z-index value of the button).*


Go to https://codepen.io/anon/pen/aPKpGo

```css
.my_header_bg_color {
    /*background-color: #FF6138;*/
    background-color: #00A388;
    z-index: 9000;
}


.margin-left20 {
    margin-left: 20px;
}

@media (min-width: 220px) {

    .my_home_banner {
        /*height: 397px;*/
        margin: auto;
        position: relative;
    }

    .my_home_banner_title {
        font-size: 20px;
        color: white;
        font-weight: bold;
    }

    .my_home_banner_subtitle {
        font-size: 12px;
        color: white;
    }

    .btn, h2, p {
        margin-bottom: 16px;
    }


}

@media (min-width:300px) {

       .my_home_banner {
        /*height: 397px;*/
        margin: auto;
        position: relative;
    }

    .my_home_banner_title {
        font-size: 36px;
        color: white;
        font-weight: bold;
    }

    .my_home_banner_subtitle {
        font-size: 12px;
        color: white;
    }

    .btn, h2, p {
        margin-bottom: 16px;
    }

    .my_home_banner_image {
        position: absolute;
        bottom: 0%;
        margin-left: 10%;
        z-index: -1;
    }

}


@media (min-width:320px) {

       .my_home_banner {
        /*height: 397px;*/
        margin: auto;
        position: relative;
    }

    .my_home_banner_title {
        font-size: 44px;
        color: white;
        font-weight: bold;
    }

    .my_home_banner_subtitle {
        font-size: 14px;
        color: white;
    }

    .btn, h2, p {
        margin-bottom: 16px;
    }

}


@media (min-width:801px) {

    .my_home_banner {
        height: 360px;
        /*font-size: 10px;*/
        /*font-weight: bold;*/
        /*color: white;*/
        position: relative;
    }

    .my_home_banner_title {
        font-size: 48px;
        color: white;
        font-weight: bold;
    }

    .my_home_banner_image {
        position: absolute;
        bottom: 05%;
        margin-left: 08%;
    }
}



@media (min-width: 992px) {

    .my_home_banner {
        height: 397px;
        /*font-size: 10px;*/
        /*font-weight: bold;*/
        /*color: white;*/
        position: relative;
    }

    .my_home_banner_title {
        font-size: 44px;
        color: white;
        font-weight: bold;
    }

    .my_home_banner_image {
        position: absolute;
        bottom: -0%;
        margin-left: 08%;
    }

}


@media (min-width:1025px) {


    .my_home_banner {
        height: 397px;
        /*font-size: 40px;*/
        /*font-weight: bold;*/
        /*color: white;*/
        position: relative;
    }

    .my_home_banner_left {
        margin-left: -40%;
    }

    .my_home_banner_title {
        font-size: 60px;
        color: white;
        font-weight: bold;
    }

    .my_home_banner_image {
        position: absolute;
        bottom: -0%;
        margin-left: -08%;
    }

}

@media (min-width:1281px) { /* hi-res laptops and desktops */


    .my_home_banner {
        height: 397px;
        /*font-size: 40px;*/
        /*font-weight: bold;*/
        /*color: white;*/
        position: relative;
    }

    .my_home_banner_left {
        margin-left: -40%;
    }

    .my_home_banner_title {
        font-size: 60px;
        color: white;
        font-weight: bold;
    }

    .my_home_banner_image {
        position: absolute;
        bottom: -0%;
        margin-left: -08%;
    }

  
}


/* Buttons Styling */

a.btn-azul {
  text-decoration: none;
  background-color: #5ba4e6;
  display: inline-block;
  text-align: center;
  vertical-align: middle;
  cursor: pointer;
  color: #fff;
  font-weight: 700;
  font-family: "Helvetica Neue",Helvetica,Arial,sans-serif;
  text-shadow: 0 -1px 0 rgba(0,0,0,.25);
  letter-spacing: 0;
  line-height: 1.2;
  -webkit-font-smoothing: antialiased;
  -webkit-box-shadow: inset 0 -2px 0 rgba(0,0,0,.15);
  -ms-box-shadow: inset 0 -2px 0 rgba(0,0,0,.15);
  -moz-box-shadow: inset 0 -2px 0 rgba(0,0,0,.15);
  -o-box-shadow: inset 0 -2px 0 rgba(0,0,0,.15);
  box-shadow: inset 0 -2px 0 rgba(0,0,0,.15);
  background-image: linear-gradient(to bottom,rgba(255,255,255,.09) 0%,rgba(0,0,0,.09) 100%);
  font-size: 1.4rem;
  padding: 22px 30px;
  border-radius: 6px;
  border:none;
}

a.btn-azul:focus {
 outline:none;
}


a.btn-azul:hover {
  text-decoration: none;
  background-color: #7ab6eb;
  display: inline-block;
  text-align: center;
  vertical-align: middle;
  cursor: pointer;
  color: #fff;
  font-weight: 700;
  font-family: "Helvetica Neue",Helvetica,Arial,sans-serif;
  text-shadow: 0 -1px 0 rgba(0,0,0,.25);
  letter-spacing: 0;
  line-height: 1.2;
  -webkit-font-smoothing: antialiased;
  -webkit-box-shadow: inset 0 -2px 0 rgba(0,0,0,.15);
  -ms-box-shadow: inset 0 -2px 0 rgba(0,0,0,.15);
  -moz-box-shadow: inset 0 -2px 0 rgba(0,0,0,.15);
  -o-box-shadow: inset 0 -2px 0 rgba(0,0,0,.15);
  box-shadow: inset 0 -2px 0 rgba(0,0,0,.15);
  background-image: linear-gradient(to bottom,rgba(255,255,255,.09) 0%,rgba(0,0,0,.09) 100%);
  font-size: 1.4rem;
  padding: 22px 30px;
  border-radius: 6px;
  border:none;
}


a.btn-naranja {
  text-decoration: none;
  background-color: #ffa31a;
  display: inline-block;
  text-align: center;
  vertical-align: middle;
  cursor: pointer;
  color: #fff;
  font-weight: 700;
  font-family: "Helvetica Neue",Helvetica,Arial,sans-serif;
  text-shadow: 0 -1px 0 rgba(0,0,0,.25);
  letter-spacing: 0;
  line-height: 1.2;
  -webkit-font-smoothing: antialiased;
  -webkit-box-shadow: inset 0 -2px 0 rgba(0,0,0,.15);
  -ms-box-shadow: inset 0 -2px 0 rgba(0,0,0,.15);
  -moz-box-shadow: inset 0 -2px 0 rgba(0,0,0,.15);
  -o-box-shadow: inset 0 -2px 0 rgba(0,0,0,.15);
  box-shadow: inset 0 -2px 0 rgba(0,0,0,.15);
  background-image: linear-gradient(to bottom,rgba(255,255,250,.09) 0%,rgba(0,0,0,.09) 100%);
  font-size: 1.4rem;
  padding: 22px 30px;
  border-radius: 6px;
  border:none;
}

a.btn-naranja:focus {
 outline:none;
}




a.btn-naranja:hover {
  text-decoration: none;
  background-color: #ffad33;
  display: inline-block;
  text-align: center;
  vertical-align: middle;
  cursor: pointer;
  color: #fff;
  font-weight: 700;
  font-family: "Helvetica Neue",Helvetica,Arial,sans-serif;
  text-shadow: 0 -1px 0 rgba(0,0,0,.25);
  letter-spacing: 0;
  line-height: 1.2;
  -webkit-font-smoothing: antialiased;
  -webkit-box-shadow: inset 0 -2px 0 rgba(0,0,0,.15);
  -ms-box-shadow: inset 0 -2px 0 rgba(0,0,0,.15);
  -moz-box-shadow: inset 0 -2px 0 rgba(0,0,0,.15);
  -o-box-shadow: inset 0 -2px 0 rgba(0,0,0,.15);
  box-shadow: inset 0 -2px 0 rgba(0,0,0,.15);
  background-image: linear-gradient(to bottom,rgba(255,255,255,.09) 0%,rgba(0,0,0,.09) 100%);
  font-size: 1.4rem;
  padding: 22px 30px;
  border-radius: 6px;
  border:none;
}
```

```html
<div class="container-fluid my_home_banner my_header_bg_color">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-7">
            <br>
            <br>
            <div class="my_home_banner_left">
                <p class="my_home_banner_title">Stickers Personalizados</p>
                <p class="my_home_banner_subtitle">Easy online ordering, 4 day turnaround and free online proofs. Free
                    shipping.</p>
                <div class="row">
                    <div class="col-md-6">
                        <a href="stickers" class="btn btn-azul text-white btn-block">Comprar</a>
                    </div>
                    <br>
                    <div class="col-md-6">
                        <a href="{% url 'shop:SamplePackPage' %}"
                           class="btn btn-naranja text-white btn-block">Muestras</a>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
            <br>
            <br>
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-5">
            <img class="my_home_banner_image" src="{% static 'img/banner-home.png' %}"
                 width="380px" height="240px">
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Basically, I changed it from -9000 to 9000 and it seems the same, and the buttons work.

Answer (score 0):

The HTML tag only active z-index when their position set to relative or absolute, for example:
 - This does not work :

```
<div>
   <div style="z-index:1">
   </div>
   <div style="z-index: 2">
   </div>
</div>
```

- But this should work:

or:

```
<div>
   <div style="position: absolute;z-index:1">
   </div>
   <div style="position: relative;z-index: 2">
   </div>
</div>
```

So based on what I point out. It just make no sense if you want to use z-index to order html tag when one tag inside another.

The reason I think you cannot click the button is that you set the outer tag z-index to -999 which basically mean the order of this outer tag is beneath some other tag.

So please open inspect console. And look for some other tag that have the same order as my_header_bg_color to see if they got z-index set higher. Or simply do like this.

```
<div class="some-other-tag"></div>
<div class="my_header_bg_color" style="position: relative; z-index: 9999">
  <a class="my_home_buttons" />    <---- remove z-index of this tag, its reduncdent
</div>
```

Edit: just check the codepen, I make it work by modify like this:

```
.my_header_bg_color {
  background-color: #00A388;
  position: relative; <---- add position: relative;
  z-index: 9000;
}
```